# Orchard CMS Content Deployment with Orchard Deployment Module

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I am evaluating Orchard 1.9.2 as I am looking for a CMS where I can have a staging area so that users can test and approve content on a staging site before committing changes to live.

I installed 1.9.2 both locally and on Azure, and also the Orchard Deployment module (Wng.Deployment). Setting up and pressing Test on the Sources and Targets tab works, but when I try to create a deployment I get the YSOD

Shape type DatePickerLocalization not found

Source file: d:\home\site\wwwroot\Modules\Wng.Deployment\Views\EditorTemplates\Parts\Deployment.Subscription.cshtml

[OrchardException: Shape type DatePickerLocalization not found]

If I enable the Shape Tracing module, the error message changes but it still doesn't work.

It appears that the Orchard Deployment Module isn't compatible with 1.9.2.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

[image: Error message]

Comment: Looking at [the module.txt](https://orcharddeployment.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Module.txt) of the module, it seems quite old. You can try opening the orchard solution, add the module and upgrade the .net target framework and see if it works.

Comment: Also, for your specific error, the shapes are renamed. Theyare now called `New.CalendarsPickerLocalization()` and `New.TimeEntryLocalization()` (see [the source](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/tree/1.9.2/src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.jQuery/Views))

Comment: Not useful to you right now, but for infos, the next minor release of Orchard (1.11) will contain a new feature called Deployments, which will provide the same features as Wng.Deployment and more.

Comment: Thanks for that, that's very good news. I haven't yet managed to find a open source CMS with good staging capabilities.